# Recursive search for a div in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Given an id of a div tag on my page i need to recursively search all children until i find a div with the given text string as it content then remove the element ...

```
function removewhereTextIs(text){
    // ???
}
```

I have been playing with using jquery for this but i can't seem to get it to work ...

```
var divs = $('#MainContent_ui_calAvailability').find('div').get()
for (div in divs) {
    alert(div.innerHtml);
}
```

I even considered the each function ...

```
var divs = $('#MainContent_ui_calAvailability').find('div').get().each(
    function () { function () { if ($(this).innerText == 'TEXT') { $(this).parent.removeChild(this); }  }
);
```

I guess this is the difference between a UI programmer and a BLL programmer ...

So ...

Any genius out there wanna help me out?

EDIT:

thanks for the help guys ... none of these seem to be working ... I'm prety sure they should work though ... bit odd ... the actual markup looks like this ...

```
<DIV style="..." id="MainContent_ui_calAvailability">
 <DIV style="...">
  <DIV style="..." class="">
   <DIV style="...">

   </DIV>
   <DIV style="...">
    TEST
   </DIV>
  </DIV>
  ...
</DIV>
```

Do any of these work for you guys???

Comment: Seems theres a lot of js wizards on here ... i'll be back for sure :) Watch this space lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('#MainContent_ui_calAvailability div').each( function () {
    if ($(this).text() == 'TEXT') { $(this).remove(); }
});
```

A few points about your function:

1)  you can combine the selector call and the find() call into one selector.

2)  get() will return dom elements, not a jQuery object, so you can't call .each() on it.

3)  You declared a function inside your each callback, but didn't actually execute it.

Comment: Ah got it ... needed to wrap this up in a document ready call ... $(document).ready(
            function () { /* your code */ } ); Thanks dennis

Answer (score 3):

If you do allow partial instead of exact matches you can use the `contains` selector:

```
$('#MainContent_ui_calAvailability div:contains("TEXT")').remove();
```

Comment: If you want to do partial matching, you can clean it up even a little bit further by calling remove() directly instead of putting it inside each().

Comment: i would have gone for this ... but i'd rather go for specifics in this case ... I really like this solution +1

Answer (score 2):

No need for an each, how about something like this?

```
$('#MainContent_ui_calAvailability div:contains(TEXT)').remove();
```

check out the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EWUkG/16/).

Comment: haha ... thanks Zeus you came to the conclusion as alp ... again very helpful :) +1

Answer (score 1):

I would look at doing this:

```
$('#MainContent_ui_calAvailability div').each(function (index, item) {
  if ($(item).text() == "TEXT")
{
   $(item).remove();
}

});
```